# Codeigniter Login Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need help in the validations of my login page and authentication of the login page also.

Controller:
     class User_authentication extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->database();
}

function index() {
    $this->session->set_userdata('message', '');
}

function loadLogin() {
    $this->load->view('index.php');
}

function authenticateUser() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Invalid Password.');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('index.php');
    }

    else {
        redirect('homepage/loadhomeView');
    }

}

function username_check($str) {
    $username = $this->input->get_post('username');

    if($str == '' || $str != $username) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The username is invalid');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->load->view('index.php');
 }
}
```

and Model:
    class User_model extends CI_Model {

```
function login_user() {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    $query = $this->query->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

kindly guide me in doing this.. thank you

Comment: Please tell us clearly where are you  getting problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use ion_auth library. http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/ It will handle this for you.

Comment: try my system login https://github.com/abedputra/Dnato-system-login with secure and fast login.